# Cloudformation: Create ElasticBeanstalk without Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

How can I create an [ElasticBeanstalk environment](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-optionsettings) without a load balancer? I haven't any options to disable it in the [aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html).

It's possible to [turn off load balancing manually](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html#using-features.managing.changetype) from AWS Management Console.

This my Cloudformation stack template:

```
WsServerEBApp:
    Type: "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Application"
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: WS Server
      Description: App for Websocket Server that will hold EB Environments

  WsServerEBEnvironemt:
      Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
      Properties:
        EnvironmentName: staging
        ApplicationName: !Ref WsServerEBApp
        CNAMEPrefix: staging
        SolutionStackName: 64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.7.3 running Docker 17.03.1-ce
        VersionLabel: !Ref WsServerEBAppVersion
        OptionSettings:
          - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
            OptionName: EC2KeyName
            Value: !Ref KeyName
          - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
            OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
            Value: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
          - Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration'
            OptionName: SecurityGroups
            Value:
              - launch-wizard-1

  WsServerEBAppVersion:
    Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion'
    Properties:
      ApplicationName: !Ref WsServerEBApp
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it using [EnvironmentType](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkenvironment) value as **SingleInstance**:

```
WsServerEBEnvironemt:
      Type: 'AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment'
      Properties:
        ....
        OptionSettings:
             ....
             - Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment
                  OptionName: EnvironmentType
                  Value: SingleInstance
```